# How to submit user prompt manually using Vercel AI SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, vercel-ai

I want to submit a JSON string of a transcript from localStorage to Chat-GPT for it to process.

However, I do not know how to use the Vercel AI SDK to submit a prompt that is not from a form.

app/grading/page.tsx

```js
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'


export default function Grading() {

  const router = useRouter();
  const rawData = localStorage.getItem('transcript')
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (!rawData) {
      router.push('/error/no-data-available')
      return
    }

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/grade', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: `{"messages": ${rawData}}`
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log(response)
          const data = await response.json();
          setResponseData(data);
        } else {
          console.log(response)
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.log('An error occured:', error)
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    
  }, [])


  return (
    <>
      <Toaster/>
      <h1>Grading your conversation...</h1>
      
      {responseData ? (
        <div>
          {responseData}

        </div>
      ): (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
      
    
    </>
  )
}
```

api/grade/route.ts

```js
// ./app/api/chat/route.ts
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai';
import { prompts } from '../../../static/prompts'
const { grading_prompt } = prompts

// Create an OpenAI API client (that's edge friendly!)
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY || '',
});

// IMPORTANT! Set the runtime to edge
export const runtime = 'edge';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  
  // Extract the `prompt` from the body of the request
  const { messages } = await req.json();
  
  const messageWithSystem = [
    {role: 'system', content: grading_prompt},
    ...messages // Add user and assistant messages after the system message
  ]

  // Ask OpenAI for a streaming chat completion given the prompt
  const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    stream: true,
    messages: messageWithSystem,
  });

  // Convert the response into a friendly text-stream
  const stream = OpenAIStream(response);
  // Respond with the stream
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

I have tried making use of the `useChat()` hook, but could not execute handleSubmit() manually.

I have also tried making a Post request like I did in the code above in page.tsx.

Of course I could also use the regular OpenAI api, but I was wondering if it was possible with Vercel AI SDK.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [useCompletion hook](https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/use-completion) to handle submitting the user prompt manually for text completion:

```
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'
import { useCompletion } from "ai/react";

export default function Grading() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const rawData = localStorage.getItem('transcript')

  const { complete, completion, isLoading } = useCompletion({
    api: "/api/grade",
    onResponse: (res) => {
      // trigger something when the response starts streaming in
      // e.g. if the user is rate limited, you can show a toast
      if (res.status === 429) {
        toast.error("You are being rate limited. Please try again later.");
      }
    },
    onFinish: () => {
      // do something with the completion result
      toast.success("Successfully generated completion!");
    },
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rawData) {
      router.push('/error/no-data-available')
      return
    }

    complete(rawData);
  }, [])


  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />
      <h1>Grading your conversation...</h1>
      <p>Current state: {isLoading ? "Generating..." : "Idle"}</p>
      {completion ? <div>{completion}</div> : <div>Loading...</div>}
    </>
  );
}
```

You still use a useEffect for handling the text completion, instead using the callback provided by the useCompletion hook (`complete(rawData)`) instead of writing your own fetch logic.  The result is kept in the `completion` output from the hook.

Answer (score 4):

May be a little late, but I found that the append() ChatHelper allows what you describe with the useChat utility.

[Scroll to ChatHelpers](https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/use-chat)

It requires that you pass a Message | CreateMessage as the first arg, and conditionally ChatRequestOptions.

You can build a simple message like so:

```
append({
  role: "user",
  content: "Message you want to send",
});
```